# Facebook og:image not displaying at full size

Tags: facebook

When sharing a video from ElfYourself.com, the OG:image being sent to Facebook is 130x130 pixels. Facebook says this is the maximum size it will display in the news feed / timeline. However, what Facebook actually displays in the feed for the image is 90x90 pixels.

Why doesn't it display the full thumbnail size? I see friends sharing links from Break.com that display at 130 pixels wide. How do their images appear at that maximum width?

Here is what we are sending as the image, for example:

The image is 130x130 but it gets displayed on facebook as 90x90.

Answer (score 2):

I have almost the same problem. The share image for me re sizes to 100x100. Since your original post I'm almost positive they have updated their API, so now it's 100x100 when it used to be 90x90. Facebooks documentation is terrible and they need to update it to reflect this change in size.

It says you can go as low as 50x50, but why in the world would you do that if they re-size the image up to 100x100, which in turn affects the image quality significantly.

So in short, the answer is that you are doing it correctly, and Facebook is resizing the image, and it's documentation for the og:image is incomplete/incorrect.

Comment: FWIW it looks like 90x90 is the best size for Facebook as of right now. But yeah, their docs woefully behind. If only they had the resources to keep them up to date... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Recently, Facebook added a debug page for this information.
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object (developers account needed)
It pops up with an error message saying that your image should be 200px wide.

They might want this that high for future developments.

Answer (score 0):

try this worked for me:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://thewebsite.com/nameofyourpic.jpeg" />`
<meta property="og:image:width" content="300" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="300" />
```