# og:image resized to 30 x 30 px by Facebook within sidebar feed and 'All activity' = Look bad

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I am playing around with the Facebook open graph.

I have added an og:image tag such that the scraper gets the image and displays it on the users timeline for my custom action.

On the activity feed that appears on the sidebar, and on the All Activity page the image is resized to 30 x 30 px which looks awful.

On the user timeline however the logo is shown sufficiently bigger that it looks good.

The logo was not designed to look good at 30 x 30 px :) For our android app for example we have a smaller icon which is much simpler.

What is one meant to do in this situation? Is there a tag (I cannot find one) which allows for an icon to be specified for the cases where a small image is needed, and to use the image in all other circumstances?

Thanks

Comment: Sadly, I think we're stuck with it. [Facebook change their images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116114/facebook-ogimage-not-displaying-at-full-size) more than most people change their socks. I think it's just one more constraint to be factored in when choosing or creating an image.

Comment: Ok so ideally I need an image that looks good at 30 x 30 px as well as 200 x 200 px... I doubt such an image can be made :) Will a scrambled blurry small image on some pages annoy/put off my users? Hmm.. what to do..

Answer (score 0):

You must make other picture on your code and rename as logo. After that you can use this code.

Note: Picture should be square in size

```
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg/jpg/png"> 
<meta property="og:image:width" content="250"> 
<meta property="og:image:height" content="250">
```